# AlertDialog not showing when not onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an Activity that have to show an AlertDialog with a ListView for the user to choose one of the options. When I put the code of the AlertDialog in the onCreate method, it works. But when somewhere else, it doesn't. There are no errors on the console.

Here is where it's called (in the Activity):

```
@Override
public void onStateChanged(IntegratorState state) {
    switch (state.getState()) {
    case AWAITING_MENU_OPTION:
        IntegratorHelper.showOptionsMenu(state, SitefMenuActivity.this).show();
        break;
    default:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), state.getState().name(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And here is where I create the Dialog (in another class):

```
public static AlertDialog showOptionsMenu(IntegratorState state, Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(state.getGatewayMessageExtra());
    String[] strings;
    strings = state.getGatewayMessage().split(";");

    final List<String> options = Arrays.asList(strings);

    builder.setAdapter(new MenuSaleAdapter(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, options),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == options.size()-1) {
                        // Do a thing
                    } else {
                        // Do other thing
                    }
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}

private static class MenuSaleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MenuSaleAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView,
                parent);
        view.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I tried to put all the code in the same Activity, but it still doesn't work. The application doesn't freeze or anything, it just don't show the Dialog. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: 1. Use a context menu + listview or 2. Use a popupmenu. Id highly suggest number 2.

Comment: I don't think these menus will do. Mostly because of their layout I think. But I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing first part to:

```
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(IntegratorState state) {
    switch (state.getState()) {
    case AWAITING_MENU_OPTION:
        IntegratorHelper.showOptionsMenu(state, SitefMenuActivity.this);
        break;
    default:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), state.getState().name(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and second part:

```
public static void showOptionsMenu(IntegratorState state, Activity activity) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setTitle(state.getGatewayMessageExtra());
    String[] strings;
    strings = state.getGatewayMessage().split(";");

    final List<String> options = Arrays.asList(strings);

    builder.setAdapter(new MenuSaleAdapter(activity,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, options),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == options.size()-1) {
                        // Do a thing
                    } else {
                        // Do other thing
                    }
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

Comment: Another option would be to use DialogFragment with an interface/callback to the original activity.  DialogFragment also handles rotation better than the standard dialogs.

Comment: I tried the updated answer but it didn't work. The funny thing is that when I put the Dialog code in the onCreate method, it works. But when it's somewhere else, it doesn't.